# Laravel: Downloaded file missing extension in some browsers

Tags: php, laravel

I have a file download function that works well on Firefox and Safari, but if I try to download the same file on Chrome or MS Edge, the file is downloaded without an extension.

Here's the function

```
public function download_chapter_file(Downloadable $downloadable, Request $request): StreamedResponse
    {
        if (!$request->hasValidSignature()) abort(401);
        $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/'.$downloadable->type];
        return Storage::download($downloadable->path,$downloadable->title,$headers);
    }
```

`$downloadable->type` is either `excel` or `pdf`. 
`$downloadable->path` is the full file path. eg `storage/app/public/downloadable/chapters/9/ycCjt0K911x3b1aFjX8i0S9Jj8.pdf` 
I have tried using
`return response()->download();` but it does not solve the problem.
I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Try this `return file_get_contents(storage_path('app/public/'.$downloadable->path));` so its now `return file_get_contents(storage_path('storage/app/public/downloadable/chapters/9/ycCjt0K911x3b1aFjX8i0S9Jj8.pdf'));`

Comment: @user15070659 I have tried `$file = file_get_contents(storage_path('app/'.$downloadable->path));
        return response($file,200,$headers);` and I'm able to stream pdf files. It doesn't solve the extension issue, infact, even the filename is now wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of trials. I finally got a working solution.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

class StorageController extends Controller
{
    public function download_chapter_file(Downloadable $downloadable, Request $request):StreamedResponse
    {
        if (!$request->hasValidSignature()) abort(401);
        $extension  = File::extension(storage_path('app/'. $downloadable->path));
        $filename = $downloadable->title.'.'.$extension;
        return Storage::download($downloadable->path,$filename);
    }
}
```

Thank you all for trying

Answer (score 0):

try this , it work with me :-

```
$headers = array(
          'Content-Type: application/pdf',
        );

return Response::download($downloadable->path,$downloadable->title,$headers);
```